# Check for valid email after user inactivity?

Tags: users, user-registration

I'm looking for a plugin that sends out a confirmation / verification email to confirm that the user still have the same email address as when they registered.

If a response is not given within 2 days, the account is deleted.

Is this possible? Anyone know of a plugin?

I'll ask now and revise later (if I need to build my own).

**EDIT**

Or, it can be something where the account is inactive until the email is confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the existence of a plugin. But here is the word of advice.

There can be two ways.

First check the user when he logs in of his activity period. If he has not logged in previously for said period of time, send him an confirmation email.

Secondly you can run a cron job at set time, and check for accounts that has been above some inactivity threshold and send them confirmation email.

I am confirm about this, that wordpress stores login time.

Comment: bT, a third word of advice (:o), your Answer would gain a lot if you added sample code and/or documentation links...